# PostgreSQL service password is reset after each Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-update, postgresql, windows-services

Daminion Server (the server based photo management software) installation insludes the PostgreSQL installation.

All is Ok after installing the both Daminion and PostgreSQL services. However after some time, after a series of Windows updates, the password for the PostgreSQL service is reset and Daminion Server can't be launched. This happened numerous of times, and each time after Windows upgrade.

Can someone point to a solution for this issue?

Comment: Which user is it running as, and how are you (re)setting the password?

Comment: Do you mean the `postgres` password within PostgreSQL, that's used when you connect with `psql`? Or do you mean the service account password, for the `postgres` Windows user created by PostgreSQL installers below version 9.2?

Comment: Craig, I meant the Windows service password.

Comment: techie007, user is postgres, and password is "SOMEPASSWORD".